# How many branches does the reverse Hilbert curve mapping have at most?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, the unit interval $[0,1]$
and the Hilbert curve mapping of this interval onto the unit square.

There also exists a reverse mapping from the unit square to the unit interval.
Now the question I have is the following:

To how many distinct values on the unit interval can a single point in the unit square map under the reverse mapping (at most)?
So basically, how many branches does the reverse Hilbert curve mapping have?
Is there even a finite amount of branches, or do there exist points in the unit-square, that have infinitely many values on the unit interval corresponding to them?

Comment: Maybe try: Hans Sagan, Space-filling curves, Springer 1994

Comment: Maybe try: A.R. Butz, Convergence with Hilbert’s space filling curve. 
J. Comput. Syst. Sci. 3, 128-146 (1969) [Zbl 0198.24504](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0198.24504) and its references.